# Wordpress Elementor custom PHP code snippets

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm using the `wordpress` pagebuilder `elementor` and since I want to add some custom code, I created a section and added the `enhanced-text-widget`, where you are supposed to add any kind of code snippets. So when I add my snippet of PHP code, it works pretty well while I'm on the developing/editor interface, on the live-site though, I can only see raw lines of code??? Can someone maybe tell what causes this issue?

I added this code inside the 'content' field of the `enhanced text widget`:

```
<section class="block">
     <?php 
         $args = array(
             'post_type' => 'cases',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'orderby' => 'rand'
          );

            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>

        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-header section-header light">
                <h5>Similiar Cases</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-content">
                <?php if ($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                   $image = get_field('case_image', $the_query->post->ID); ?>
                    <div class="slide-box">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>" /></a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-controls">
                <div class="prev"></div>
                <div class="next"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

which gives me this in the browser:

```
\'cases\', \'post_status\' => \'publish\', \'orderby\' => \'rand\' ); 
$the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
Similiar cases have_posts() ) : while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : 
$the_query->the_post(); $image = get_field(\'case_image\', $the_query->post >ID); ?>
<a href="\"><img src="\" />
```

Please help someone?